# UNIX split command splitting this file, but what names are resulting?

Tags: unix

We receive a big csv file from a client (500k lines, est) that we split into smaller chunks using the `split` command.

You can see how we're using the command below, but my bash knowledge is a bit rusty, could someone refresh me on the `${processFile}_` bit below, and how the files are being named in the end?  Not recalling what the underscore does...

```
split -l 50000 $PROCESSING_CURRENT_DIR/$processFile ${processFile}_
```

Comment: `${processFile}_` is prefix for generated filenames after `split`

Comment: `$processFile` is interpolated into the command line (replaced by its value) before `split` is invoked. `${processFile}` means the same thing, but without the braces, the `_` which follows would be interpreted as part of the identifier.  Anyway, the `processFile` variable has nothing to do with `split`. Try reading the man page: `man split`. The optional argument after the file is a prefix that is used for naming the split files.

Comment: `split` is not part of bash -- it can be used even without any shell installed at all. For example, Python's `subprocess.Popen(['split', '-l', '50000', processDir+'/'+processFile, processFile+'_'])` wouldn't run any shell, but would still invoke `split` with an equivalent argument list (assuming you had Python variables by the given names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with bash but how [`split(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) command processes its arguments to split the input.

Syntax is:

> ```
>    split [OPTION]... [FILE [PREFIX]]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Output pieces of FILE to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is 'x'.
>
> ```
>    With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
> ```

So it uses the given prefix and makes output files.